# Problems installing appdynamics

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, appdynamics

I have installed Appdynamics lite on my server and it worked fine when I used to run my tomcat instance with root user. But from the time I have created a new user "Tomcat" and start executing my apache tomcat with this user, I am not able to run appdynamics. I have copied the javaagent at this location with all rights(read,write,execute) to tomcat "/home/tomcat/profiler/AppServerLite". It throws an exception as follows :

```
    Install Directory resolved to[/home/tomcat/profiler/AppServerLite]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Agent Installation Directory [/home/tomcat/profiler/AppServerLite]
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint.addThirdPartyURLs(AgentEntryPoint.java:190)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint.premain(AgentEntryPoint.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:343)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:358)
Install Directory resolved to[/home/tomcat/profiler/AppServerLite]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Agent Installation Directory [/home/tomcat/profiler/AppServerLite]
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint.addThirdPartyURLs(AgentEntryPoint.java:190)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint.premain(AgentEntryPoint.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:343)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:358)
18 Apr, 2013 1:57:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
```

Answer (score 2):

You should copy all files to run the agent, not just javaagent.jar.

This is a thread about it. http://appsphere.appdynamics.com/t5/Lite-for-Java/Keep-getting-a-quot-Invalid-Agent-Installation-Directory-quot-on/td-p/1151

Answer (score 1):

A great place to ask this question would be on the AppDynamics discussion forums so that AppDynamics support can answer you directly... http://appsphere.appdynamics.com/t5/Discussions/ct-p/Discussions

I'm guessing there is a permissions issue somewhere.